# Rails to_json different than received JSON

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3.1, restkit

I am trying to figure out why JSON on the server is different than what is being received in my mobile app using Restkit.  When I look at the JSON representation of my objects with `puts @items.to_json`, I get the following:

```
[{"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-19T19:42:44Z","id":4,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Biz Cards","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-19T19:42:44Z","url":"","user_id":3}},
 {"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-20T19:37:33Z","id":5,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Hummus","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-20T19:37:33Z","url":"","user_id":3}},
 {"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-20T20:01:57Z","id":7,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Wine","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-20T20:01:57Z","url":"","user_id":3}},
 {"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-25T19:57:33Z","id":9,"json_event_id":null,"name":"this","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-25T19:57:33Z","url":"","user_id":3}}]
```

However, when I view the JSON received on the client side, I get a new JSON element with all nulls, including the ID (last element here):

```
[{"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-19T19:42:44Z","id":4,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Biz Cards","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-19T19:42:44Z","url":"","user_id":3}},
 {"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-20T19:37:33Z","id":5,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Hummus","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-20T19:37:33Z","url":"","user_id":3}}, 
 {"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-20T20:01:57Z","id":7,"json_event_id":null,"name":"Wine","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-20T20:01:57Z","url":"","user_id":3}}, 
 {"item":{"created_at":"2012-04-25T19:57:33Z","id":9,"json_event_id":null,"name":"this","theme_id":null,"updated_at":"2012-04-25T19:57:33Z","url":"","user_id":3}}, 
 {"item":{"created_at":null,"id":null,"json_event_id":null,"name":null,"theme_id":null,"updated_at":null,"url":null,"user_id":3}}]
```

Why is `@items.to_json` returning different JSON than `format.json { render json: @items }` and how can I respond with the correct `@items.to_json`?

**EDIT**
Here is the code populating @items:

```
@items = current_user.items
```

**EDIT**
This also appears to only happen when I populate the @items based on the current_user:

```
@items = current_user.items
```

There is no additional null object when I just do all:

```
@items = Item.all
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you're assigning to `@items`?

Comment: Just did and thanks for editing to improve my formatting Dylan!

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to "intercept" the JSON right before 'render json' and remove anything with an "id":null?